# Using 'sorted' a second time can't find file/dir

Tags: python, sorting

Trying to simply sort two directories, and it works fine the first time, but when I call it a second time (last line below, for `tallFiles`), it throws a '`No such file or directory` error, even though it correctly lists the first sorted file in that directory.

```
import os
import datetime
from pathlib import Path

wallDir = Path('/Users/leigh/Dropbox/Photos/Wallpaper')
tallDir = Path('/Users/leigh/Dropbox/Photos/Wallpaper/Tall')

wallFiles = sorted(os.listdir(wallDir), key=lambda t: -os.stat(t).st_mtime)
tallFiles = sorted(os.listdir(tallDir), key=lambda t: -os.stat(t).st_mtime)
```

Throws this error:

```
leigh@outpost31 Wallpaper % python3 ~/Dropbox/Development/rename.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/leigh/Dropbox/Development/rename.py", line 9, in <module>
    tallFiles = sorted(os.listdir(tallDir), key=lambda t: -os.stat(t).st_mtime)
  File "/Users/leigh/Dropbox/Development/rename.py", line 9, in <lambda>
    tallFiles = sorted(os.listdir(tallDir), key=lambda t: -os.stat(t).st_mtime)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'holjfmgopwk81.jpg'
```

The file and path absolutely exist...

Comment: The file doesn't exist *in the current directory*. You'd need to pass the directory name too, or `chdir` into it. There are existing questions that cover this, and I think they'll fully answer your question, but LMK if not.

Comment: `key=lambda t: -os.stat(t).st_mtime` You're only passing the bare filename into `os.stat()`, but you need the directory name also, because that file does not exist  in the current working directory.

Comment: Oh, for heaven's sake...thank you.